# Array is getting Wiped

Tags: java, android, arrays

So I am in the middle of a Challenge from a book I am reading. The challenge says that I do some questions at the users of the app and they should answer *True* or *False*. Also they have the option to cheat but when they gone back to the question answer must not be acceptable.
So I created a Boolean Array where I save the status of the "cheater". *True* if he cheats and *False* if he doesn't cheat. But after one full rotation of the Questions the Array is Wiped. Why is this happening? What I am doing wrong?

Here is my main code for the Quiz Activity:

```
public class QuizActivity extends Activity {

private Button mTrueButton;
private Button mFalseButton;
private Button mNextButton;
private Button mCheatButton;
private TextView mQuestionTextView;
private static final String TAG = "QuizActivity";
private static final String KEY_INDEX = "index";
private static final String CHEATER_BOOLEAN = "cheat";

private TrueFalse[] mQuestionBank = new TrueFalse[] {
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_oceans, true),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_mideast, false),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_africa, false),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_americas, true),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_asia, true),
    };

private boolean[] mCheatBank = new boolean[mQuestionBank.length];

private int mCurrentIndex = 0;
private boolean mIsCheater;

private void updateQuestion() {
    int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getQuestion();
    mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
}

private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue) {
    boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isTrueQuestion();

    int messageResId = 0;


    if(mIsCheater) {
        messageResId = R.string.judgment_toast;
    } else {
    if (userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
        messageResId = R.string.correct_toast;
    } else {
        messageResId = R.string.incorrect_toast;
    }
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate(Bundle) called");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    mQuestionTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
    mQuestionTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
            mIsCheater = false;
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });

    mTrueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.true_button);
    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkAnswer(true);        
        }
    });
    mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkAnswer(false); 
        }
    });

    mNextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
            mIsCheater = mCheatBank[mCurrentIndex];
            updateQuestion();
        }
    }); 

    mCheatButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cheat_button);
    mCheatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(QuizActivity.this,CheatActivity.class);
            boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isTrueQuestion();
            i.putExtra(CheatActivity.EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, answerIsTrue);
            startActivityForResult(i,0);
        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, 0);
        mIsCheater = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(CHEATER_BOOLEAN, false);
    }
    updateQuestion();
} // End of onCreate(Bundle) method

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onActivityResult called");
    if (data == null) {
        return;
    }
    mIsCheater = data.getBooleanExtra(CheatActivity.EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, false);
    mCheatBank[mCurrentIndex] = mIsCheater;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
    savedInstanceState.putInt(KEY_INDEX, mCurrentIndex);
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean(CHEATER_BOOLEAN, mIsCheater);
}
```

Edit 1: Here is the code from the other classes because someone asked.

**CheatActivity Code:**

```
public class CheatActivity extends Activity {
   public static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE = "com.bignerrandch.android.geoquiz.answer_is_true";
   public static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN = "com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.answer_shown";

   private boolean mAnswerIsTrue;
   private boolean mCheater;

   private TextView mAnswerTextView;
   private Button mShowAnswer;

   private void setAnswerShownResult(boolean isAnswerShown) {
      Intent data = new Intent();
      data.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, isAnswerShown);
      setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_cheat);

      mAnswerIsTrue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, false);

      mAnswerTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answerTextView);

      mCheater = false;
      if (savedInstanceState != null) {
         mCheater = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, false);
         setAnswerShownResult(mCheater);

         if (mAnswerIsTrue) {
            mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.true_button);
         }
         else {
            mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.false_button);
         }
       } else {
          setAnswerShownResult(false);
       }

      mShowAnswer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.showAnswerButton);
      mShowAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mAnswerIsTrue) {
               mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.true_button);
            }
            else {
               mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.false_button);
            }

            setAnswerShownResult(true);

            mCheater = true;
         }
      });
   }

   @Override
   public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
      savedInstanceState.putBoolean(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, mCheater);
   }

}
```

**TrueFalse Code:**

```
public class TrueFalse{
private int mQuestion;
private boolean mTrueQuestion;

public TrueFalse(int question, boolean trueQuestion) {
    mQuestion = question;
    mTrueQuestion = trueQuestion;
}


public int getQuestion() {
    return mQuestion;
}

public void setQuestion(int question) {
    mQuestion = question;
}

public boolean isTrueQuestion() {
    return mTrueQuestion;
}

public void setTrueQuestion(boolean trueQuestion) {
    mTrueQuestion = trueQuestion;
}   
}
```

Comment: Which book are you reading? :P Just out of curiosity

Comment: Android Programming - The Big Nerd Ranch Guide by
Bill Phillips and Brian Hardy.

Comment: Can you explain `But after one full rotation of the Questions the Array is Wiped`?

Comment: this is your all source code? any other portion

Comment: Yeah I can. If the cheater push the cheat button,lets say at the first question, his answer isn't acceptable and he gets a "Toast". But if he press the next button and go through all the questions and comes back at first, then he can answer the question without problem.

Comment: can you make it static private TrueFalse[] mQuestionBank

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you mean by wiped. But I think your problem is that you are using a member variable to set your array values. So you are setting each element of your array to that value. So essentially the entire array will be set to what ever the final state of mIsCheater is.

Comment: The `mCheatBank` array is a `boolean[]`, meaning its values are primitives, and not object references.